How to select in($1) using sqlc and golang?
I have been working in SQLC and Go, I am struggling to find items using in or any
my db used ids as Bigserial type, which is being translated as int64 in my table types as you can see in my TB_COMMENTS
-- sql schema
CREATE TABLE TB_COMMENTS
(
    ID         BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONTENT    TEXT      NOT NULL,
    POST_ID    BIGSERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES TB_POSTS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    AUTHOR_ID  BIGSERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES TB_USERS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

- Go struct generated

type TbComment struct {
    ID        int64            `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt pgtype.Timestamp `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt pgtype.Timestamp `json:"updated_at"`
    Content   string           `json:"content"`
    PostID    int64            `json:"post_id"`
    AuthorID  int64            `json:"author_id"`
}

I get some issues with that. I am trying to the select in, as you can see the generated FindCommentsByIds, is expecting a int64 and not a slice of int64([] int64)
const findCommentsByIds = `-- name: FindCommentsByIds :many
select c.id, c.created_at, c.updated_at, c.content, c.post_id, c.author_id from TB_COMMENTS c where c.id in ($1)
`

func (q *Queries) FindCommentsByIds(ctx context.Context, id int64) ([]TbComment, error) {
    rows, err := q.db.Query(ctx, findCommentsByIds, id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    var items []TbComment
    for rows.Next() {
        var i TbComment
        if err := rows.Scan(
            &i.ID,
            &i.CreatedAt,
            &i.UpdatedAt,
            &i.Content,
            &i.PostID,
            &i.AuthorID,
        ); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        items = append(items, i)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return items, nil
}

If I change my select to select c.* from TB_COMMENTS c where c.id = ANY ($1::int[]);
It awaits dollar_1 []int32 intead of dollar_1 []int64
The question is: Is there a way to my resulting method expect []int64?
I am using postgres database. and sqlc version v1.27.0
sqlc.yml
version: "2"
sql:
  - engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "./internal/db/queries.sql"
    schema: "./internal/db/schema.sql"
    gen:
      go:
        package: "repository"
        out: "internal/db/repository"
        sql_package: "pgx/v5"
        emit_json_tags: true





The answer is simpler then I though. Sqlc( At least for postgres) can't translate the in to a list of items. The result should be got using the ANY and bigserial
select c.* from TB_COMMENTS c where c.id = ANY ($1::BIGSERIAL[]);

